# A Step in Calculating the Cup Product on $\mathbf RP^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We write $P^k$ to denote $\mathbf RP^k$ and always work with $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ coefficients.

On pg 221 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, there is the following diagram

[image]

Here by $P^{i-1}$ we mean the subspace of $P^n$ consisting of points represented by vectors in $\mathbf R^{n+1}$ whose last $n-(i-1)$ coordinates are $0$. Similarly for $P^i$.

By $P^j$ we mean the subspace of $P^n$ consisting of points represented by vectors in $\mathbf R^{n+1}$ having the first $i$ coordinates $0$.

> **Question.** Hatcher says that the maps in the left-hand square are all isomorphisms *because of cellular cohomology.* I am stuggling to see how.

The way I cann see the top map in the left hand square is an isomorphism is via the following argument.

We have part of the long exact sequence for the pair $(P^n, P^{i-1})$

$$H^i(P^n, P^{i-1})\rightarrow H^i(P^n)\rightarrow H^i(P^{i-1})\rightarrow \cdots$$

The group $H^i(P^n, P^{i-1})$ is $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ because $H^i(P^n, P^{i-1})\cong H^i(P^n/P^{i-1}))$. Now $P^n/P^{i-1}$ is homeomorphic to the wedge sum of shperes, one for each of the dimensions $i, i+1, \ldots, n$.

The group $H^i(P^n)$ is $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ because of the universal coefficient theorem and because $H_i(P^n)=\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

Lastly, $H^i(P^{i-1})=0$ because of cellular cohomology and the fact that $P^{i-1}$ has no cell in the $i$-th dimension.

Thus the map $H^i(P^n, P^{i-1})\to H^i(P^n)$ is a surjection, and since both groups are $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, this map is an isomorphism.

Similarly one can show that the bottom map in the left-hand square is an isomorphism.

Is there an easier way to see that these maps are isomorphisms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maps $H^i(\Bbb P^n, \Bbb P^{i-1}) \to H^i(\Bbb P^n)$ and $H^i(\Bbb P^i,\Bbb P^{i-1}) \to H^i(\Bbb P^i)$ in the leftmost square are induced by the inclusion of pairs $(\Bbb P^n, \emptyset) \hookrightarrow (\Bbb P^n, \Bbb P^{i-1})$ and $(\Bbb P^i, \emptyset) \hookrightarrow (\Bbb P^i, \Bbb P^{i-1})$. Write down the long exact sequence of the pairs - let's do this for the first.

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} H^{i-1}(\Bbb P^n) @>>> H^{i-1}(\Bbb P^{i-1}) @>\partial>> H^i(\Bbb P^n, \Bbb P^{i-1}) @>>> H^i(\Bbb P^n) @>>> H^i(\Bbb P^{i-1}) \end{CD}$$

The map in there is exactly the map induced by the inclusion mentioned above. The rightmost term $H^i(\Bbb P^{i-1})$ is zero because dimension of the cohomology is larger. The leftmost map is isomorphism because that's what cellular cohomology says - that makes the snake map $\partial$ zero. Hence $H^i(\Bbb P^n, \Bbb P^{i-1}) \to H^i(\Bbb P^n)$ is an isomorphism.

Similar logic can be used for the other vertical map.