# Using Cellular Cohomology for computing $H^n(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{n-1})$, Hatcher's Theorem 3.19.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

In Hatcher p.221, with the notation $\mathbf{P}^n$ for $\mathbb{RP}^n$, and all cohomology groups in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, he says

[image]

I can see from the l.e.s. on the cohomology of the pair $(\mathbf{P}^n, \mathbf{P}^{n-1})$ the exact sequence

$0 = H^n(\mathbf{P}^{n-1})\leftarrow H^n(\mathbf{P}^n)\xleftarrow{j^*} H^n(\mathbf{P}^n, \mathbf{P}^{n-1})\xleftarrow{\partial} H^{n-1}(\mathbf{P}^{n-1})\xleftarrow{i^*} H^{n-1}(\mathbf{P}^n)$

But then I would need to have $\partial = 0$ for the map $j^*$ to be an isomorphism.

This could be established by showing that the map $i^*$ is an isomorphism.

I am assuming this is what Hatcher means, also based on the answer in [A Step in Calculating the Cup Product on $\mathbf RP^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061272/a-step-in-calculating-the-cup-product-on-mathbf-rpn).

How do we know $i^*$ is indeed an isomorphism?
As pointed out, this is mentioned in the second line of Hatcher's proof:

"The inclusion $\mathbf{P}^{n-1}\to \mathbf{P}^n$ induces an isomorphism on $H^i$, for $i\leq n-1$."

Would someone clarify why this statement is true?

Comment: The second line of Hatcher's proof starts *Since the inclusion $P^{n-1}\hookrightarrow P^n$ induces an isomorphism on $H^i$ for $i\leq n-1$*. I'm guessing that you have computed the cohomology groups of $H^*P^{n-1}$ at some previous point. Btw, you should mention that all coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Let $X$ be a CW complex with n-skeleton $X_n$. Then by cellular cohomology the inclusion $X_n\hookrightarrow X$ induces isomorphisms $H^iX\xrightarrow\cong H^iX_n$ for all $i<n-1$, and an injection $H^nX\xrightarrow\cong H^nX_n$. In the case at hand both $H^n(P^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $H^n(P^{n-1};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus cellular cohomology gives you an injection $\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$.